# Passport - Duo Strategy "ERR|The username passed to sign_request() is invalid"

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I am currently playing about with duo in node.js using passport to see if I can implement it into a test application....I am using a passport-duo strat to do this and the GitHub repo for that is located [here](https://github.com/basharal/passport-duo) where I have attempted to use the example given but cant get it to work within my own application.

But it seems every time I go to load the iframe for duo it keeps throw me the same error `ERR|The username passed to sign_request() is invalid.`

The snippet it keeps falling over at is the following:

```
app.get('/login-duo', checkLoggedIn, function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.user);
    console.log(req.user['id']);
    console.log(req.query.host);
    console.log(req.query.post_action);
    console.log(req.query.signed_request);
    var username= req.user['id'];
    res.render('login-duo', {
        user : req.user['id'],
        host : req.query.host,
        post_action : req.query.post_action,
        sig_request : req.query.signed_request
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</script>
<style>
  body {
    background: #f1f1f1;
  }
  .iframe_div {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 620px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #duo_iframe {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  div {
    background: transparent;
  }
</style>
<form method="POST" style="display:none;" id="duo_form">
</form>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <head>
    <title>Passport-Duo Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="iframe_div">
    <iframe id="duo_iframe" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
  </body>
  <script src="js/Duo-Web-v1.bundled.min.js"></script>
<script>
Duo.init({
  'host': '<%= host %>',
  'post_action': '<%= post_action %>',
  'sig_request': '<%= sig_request %>'
});
</script>
</html>
```

Wondering anyone with any experience with implementing passport-duo and has an idea as to why the `sig_request` is throwing back that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Passport-Duo package](https://github.com/basharal/passport-duo) you mentioned [declares](https://github.com/basharal/passport-duo/blob/master/package.json#L32) `duo_web` as a dependency.

[duo_nodejs (duo_web)](https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_nodejs) is the package returning this error. The error is declared in the [`duo.js` file](https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_nodejs/blob/master/duo.js#L14).

If we take a look at [the source code](https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_nodejs/blob/master/duo.js#L118-L123) where this error is used, the only occurences are:

```
exports.sign_request = function (ikey, skey, akey, username) {
  if (!username || username.length < 1) {
    return ERR_USER;
  }
  if (username.indexOf('|') !== -1) {
    return ERR_USER;
  }

  // ...
  // Truncated for the example...
  // ...
}
```

The code is returning this error only in 3 conditions:

- The username is not defined
- The username is empty
- The username contains the character `|`

Back to [Passport-Duo](https://github.com/basharal/passport-duo), this function `sign_request` is called by the [strategy](https://github.com/basharal/passport-duo/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L72) using the following code:

```
var signed = duo.sign_request(this._ikey, this._skey, this._akey, req.user.email);
```

It seems that your `req.user.email` is matching one the previous conditions returning this error. With the code provided in the question, it's impossible to check which one it is but you should definitely check this variable and ensure none of this conditions are true.